# Linker errors building OpenMPI

Tags: linux, docker, fedora, openmpi

When attempting to build OpenMPI in a Fedora 34 Docker image I get the following linker errors:

```
#22 77.36 make[2]: Entering directory '/build/openmpi-4.1.1/opal/tools/wrappers'
#22 77.37   CC       opal_wrapper.o
#22 77.67   CCLD     opal_wrapper
#22 77.81 /usr/bin/ld: ../../../opal/.libs/libopen-pal.so: undefined reference to `opal_util_keyval_yytext'
#22 77.81 /usr/bin/ld: ../../../opal/.libs/libopen-pal.so: undefined reference to `opal_util_keyval_yyin'
#22 77.81 /usr/bin/ld: ../../../opal/.libs/libopen-pal.so: undefined reference to `opal_util_keyval_yylineno'
#22 77.81 /usr/bin/ld: ../../../opal/.libs/libopen-pal.so: undefined reference to `opal_util_keyval_yynewlines'
#22 77.81 /usr/bin/ld: ../../../opal/.libs/libopen-pal.so: undefined reference to `opal_util_keyval_yylex'
#22 77.81 /usr/bin/ld: ../../../opal/.libs/libopen-pal.so: undefined reference to `opal_util_keyval_parse_done'
#22 77.81 /usr/bin/ld: ../../../opal/.libs/libopen-pal.so: undefined reference to `opal_util_keyval_yylex_destroy'
#22 77.81 /usr/bin/ld: ../../../opal/.libs/libopen-pal.so: undefined reference to `opal_util_keyval_init_buffer'
#22 77.81 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My configure command is just `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/openmpi`.

I also tried `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/openmpi --disable-silent-rules --enable-builtin-atomics --with-hwloc=/usr --with-libevent=external --with-pmix=external --with-valgrind` (similar to what is in the Fedora spec file for OpenMPI) but that produces the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

After I posted a [message](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@lists.open-mpi.org//msg34526.html) on the OpenMPI users list someone [pointed out the line](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@lists.open-mpi.org//msg34532.html)

```
../../libtool: line 5705: find: command not found
```

in the [make output](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@lists.open-mpi.org//msg34530.html). The `find` command in Fedora is provided by the `findutils` package. After installing `findutils` in the image I was able to build OpenMPI successfully.

Comment: In the meantime I did two runs with building openmpi-4.1.1, and of course no errors with a default Fedora 34 install. Results: rpm packages, etc. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wgIVc6Z6VCIWuPMg6pfY_iXjm4kzD6Wg?usp=sharing

Comment: @KnudLarsen, did you do your builds from the Fedora Docker image? Other environments likely come with findutils already installed, but the Docker image seems not to have it by default.

Comment: Fedora Docker image : No. ....  The OS is installed to a hard disk partition. ...... Sorry that I misread your question.